# User showing not enrolled in 2FA but account detail shows 2FA is on - is this a reporting error

Tags: google-workspace-for-business, security, authentication, g-suite-administrator

I am a gsuite administrator and in doing my regular report reviews I have found a user, that on the standard Security report shows they are not enrolled in 2FA.  However, when I click on the user to get account details, it shows they have 2FA "On" and "Enforced".  Could this be a reporting error and what would drive this?  Perhaps how they enrolled such as not providing a backup email or phone #.   Can I have the user re-enroll and if so how can that be done?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Some changes might take up to 24hrs to be propagated across the different servers. Considering this, please add more details like when the user account was created, when was enrolled in 2FA, and a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]. P.S. Have you already submitted a support ticket?

Comment: I don't know how this resolved for you, but I came here with the same problem and it eventually resolved itself on its own. It appears there can be some lag on the UI which can be confusing. For me it took about a day from then the user enabled 2FA to when the UI reflected enrollment properly on both pages.